# Как пишется выражение "Эх(,) и повезло же нам"?

Tags: запятая

***Эх(,) и повезло же нам.***
 Нужна ли здесь запятая? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Не нужна здесь запятая.

Возможны две линии аргументации.
-1. Есть подозрение, что "эх" здесь - усилительная частица.
В этом случае запятая не нужна. Дело в том, что **междометие** эх выражает досаду, сожаление. А частица - как здесь -  сама по себе  ничего не выражает, только усиливает.

-2. "Эх и" - одно из тех целостных сочетаний, про которые и говорится, что запятая не нужна.
По Розенталю:  
Примечание 2. Внутри цельных сочетаний ох (ух, ой) как (какой) (в значении «очень, весьма, страшно», «замечательный, изумительный, ужасный»), а также цельных сочетаний ах ты, ах вы, ах он, ух ты, эх ты, ай да, ах и, **эх и**, ух и, эй и, ох эти, эк его и т.п. **запятая не ставится**, например: ...Подчас в каждом приятном слове ее торчала ух какая булавка (Гоголь); Самонадеянности море ох как не любит! (Л. Соболев); Мы могли бы получить ой какие увечья (Д. Бедный); Это, брат, ух как горько и ух как подло (Гл. Успенский); Ах ты жестокий! Ах он лиса! Ах они плуты прожженные! Ох эти сплетницы! Эх эти шалунишки! Эх и пляски! Ух и лошадь! Ай да Михаил Андреевич, настоящий цыган! (Л. Толстой); Ай да молодец мичман! (Станюкович); Эк его разобрало! (Гоголь); Эк ты напугал меня... (Мамин-Сибиряк). Ср. в предложениях с повторяющимися словами: Тяжко ему, ох тяжко! Достанется тебе на орехи, ух достанется! Хочется его подразнить, ой хочется! Приятно на солнышке, ах приятно!
*(Выделено мной - b-us)*
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm

Answer (score 0):

Да, здесь запятая нужна, поскольку междометия *эй, ах, о, ох, эх, ну* и т.д. выделяются запятыми, за исключением таких устоявшихся выражений, как, например, "эй ты".